# System Freeze after launching Apportable app

Tags: osx-mavericks, apportable

I am brand new to Apportable.  I installed and am able to launch the sample Spin app on my Android device.  However, after launch, my system is completely frozen and will not respond to any trackpad or keyboard touch.  I hard booted and tried again with an iOS app I developed with the same results.

System: 
MacBook Pro 15" Early 2011 running OSX 10.9
16GB RAM, 20 GB disk space available

Xcode 4.6

Any ideas why this is happening and what I can do to prevent it?  Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here. My Macbook Pro Retina 13" just freezed after launching the apportable app.

Comment: I had "freeze" problem with AFT as well.  However, it is not system freeze, just the keyboard and trackpad "offline" due to the USB system.  Somehow, if I insert a USB stick and remove it, it may bring the USB system back to live.  The Mac isn't freeze because (1) if it is playing music, it continues, (2) if I have a BT mouse connected, it still working.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes while copying the apk to the device, the USB driver gets blocked for a few seconds. If this is the same issue, then your system should return to normal pretty quickly (no more than five seconds on most machines).

If that isn't the case for you, you can try the following command:

```
MTP=no apportable load
```

If you still have the issue after that, something else is going on that I have never seen.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I have to hard reboot.

Comment: MTP=no disables using MTP to transfer the apk. It's slower, but it keep the bug from happening. It's the combination of Mavericks and our transfer tool not working well together. This should be addressed in either the next SDK update or in the latest SDK update. The SDK should warn you that an update_toolchain is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and `MTP=no apportable load` solved it for me.